# How to extract 2 coordinates pairs out of a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, coordinates

I'm new to python an got stuck in a kinda trivial question that i'm just not able to solve. I try to extract 2 coordinate pairs out of a string and got stuck in that the string doesnt have av common divider like a comma.

My strings look like this:

```
&BBOX=151406.25%2C6579062.5%2C151875%2C6579531.25&
&BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576689.453125%2C156328.125%2C6576718.75
&BBOX=156328.125,6576806.640625%2C156357.421875%2C6576835.9375
&BBOX=156328.125,6576748.046875,156357.421875,6576777.34375& ?BBOX=156328%2C125%2C6576777%2C34375%2C156357%2C421875%2C6576806%2C640625&
&BBOX=156269.53125%2C6576689.453125%2C156298.828125%2C6576718.75&
&BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576718.75%2C156328.125%2C6576748.046875
?BBOX=156386.71875%2C6576806.640625%2C156416.015625%2C6576835.9375&
```

Every string starts with `"BBOX="` and after that has 4 coordinates in it. `x_min`, `y_min`, `x_max`, and `y_max`. I use `"BBOX="` to find where in a much longer string my coordinates are located

`x_min` and `x_max` should be 6 digits and `y_min` and `y_max` should be 7 digits. 
They can be float values or integer values.

I thought that I would split up the coordinates in a part before the . and after the . but I really wonder if that's the way to go

Right now my regex looks like this:

```
rexp_bbox = r"(^.+BBOX=(?P<bbox_xmin_before>\d.*?)[.,%&\s](?P<bbox_xmin_after>.*?)[.,%2C&\s](?P<bbox_ymin_before>\d.*?)[.,%&\s](?P<bbox_ymin_after>.*?)[.,%&\s](?P<bbox_xmax_before>\d.*?)[.,%&\s](?P<bbox_xmax_after>.*?)[.,%&\s](?P<bbox_ymax_before>\d.*?)[.,%&\s](?P<bbox_ymax_after>.*?)[.,%&\s])"
```

**How would you construct a regex to extract the two coordinate pairs?**

Comment: Is that one large string? Or is each line a separate string?

Comment: Is % not a common divider?

Comment: @JimWright: Each line is a separate string

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output should look like? Or at least highlight which in the string is actually a coordinate.

Comment: What were the problems with the split?

Comment: @jstein123: It can be a comma or a %2C (which i belive is comma in html)

Comment: The output should look like 
{{151406.25, 6579062.5}, {151875, 6579531.25}} 

{{156298.828125, 6576689.453125}, {156328.125, 6576718.75}}

{{156328.125, 6576806.640625}, {156357.421875, 6576835.9375}}

{{156328.125, 6576748.046875}, {156357.421875, 6576777.34375}}

Comment: Your comments where very helpful in getting me thinking in the right way. I modified my regex to: 

BBOX=(?P<xmin>\d.*?)(%2C)(?P<ymin>\d.*?)(%2C)(?P<xmax>\d.*?)(%2C)(?P<ymax>\d.*?)(\s|&)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `"(?:.*BBOX=)(\d{6}(?:\.?[\d]*))(?:%2C|,)(\d{7}(?:\.?[\d]*))(?:%2C|,)(\d{6}(?:\.?[\d]*))(?:%2C|,)(\d{7}(?:\.?[\d]*))"` works and will extract the coordinates into 4 groups. Group 1 = `min_x`, group 2 = `min_y`, group 3 = `max_x`, group 4 = `max_y`.

The following code shows the pattern in action:

```
import re

orig_coords = [
  '&BBOX=151406.25%2C6579062.5%2C151875%2C6579531.25&',
  '&BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576689.453125%2C156328.125%2C6576718.75',
  '&BBOX=156328.125,6576806.640625%2C156357.421875%2C6576835.9375',
  '&BBOX=156328.125,6576748.046875,156357.421875,6576777.34375&',
  '?BBOX=156328%2C125%2C6576777%2C34375%2C156357%2C421875%2C6576806%2C640625&',
  '&BBOX=156269.53125%2C6576689.453125%2C156298.828125%2C6576718.75&',
  '&BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576718.75%2C156328.125%2C6576748.046875',
  '?BBOX=156386.71875%2C6576806.640625%2C156416.015625%2C6576835.9375&'
]

bbox_start = "(?:.*BBOX=)"
separator = "(?:%2C|,)"
coord_6 = "(\d{6}(?:\.?[\d]*))"
coord_7 = "(\d{7}(?:\.?[\d]*))"
regex_str = bbox_start + coord_6 + separator + coord_7 + separator + coord_6 + separator + coord_7
reg = re.compile(regex_str)

for c in orig_coords:
  r = reg.match(c)
  if r:
    print('Coordinates for {}'.format(c))
    print('x_min: {} x_max: {}'.format(r.group(1), r.group(3)))
    print('y_min: {} y_max: {}'.format(r.group(2), r.group(4)))
  else:
    print('No match for {}'.format(c))
```

Output:

```
Coordinates for &BBOX=151406.25%2C6579062.5%2C151875%2C6579531.25&
x_min: 151406.25 x_max: 151875
y_min: 6579062.5 y_max: 6579531.25
Coordinates for &BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576689.453125%2C156328.125%2C6576718.75
x_min: 156298.828125 x_max: 156328.125
y_min: 6576689.453125 y_max: 6576718.75
Coordinates for &BBOX=156328.125,6576806.640625%2C156357.421875%2C6576835.9375
x_min: 156328.125 x_max: 156357.421875
y_min: 6576806.640625 y_max: 6576835.9375
Coordinates for &BBOX=156328.125,6576748.046875,156357.421875,6576777.34375&
x_min: 156328.125 x_max: 156357.421875
y_min: 6576748.046875 y_max: 6576777.34375
No match for ?BBOX=156328%2C125%2C6576777%2C34375%2C156357%2C421875%2C6576806%2C640625&
Coordinates for &BBOX=156269.53125%2C6576689.453125%2C156298.828125%2C6576718.75&
x_min: 156269.53125 x_max: 156298.828125
y_min: 6576689.453125 y_max: 6576718.75
Coordinates for &BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576718.75%2C156328.125%2C6576748.046875
x_min: 156298.828125 x_max: 156328.125
y_min: 6576718.75 y_max: 6576748.046875
Coordinates for ?BBOX=156386.71875%2C6576806.640625%2C156416.015625%2C6576835.9375&
x_min: 156386.71875 x_max: 156416.015625
y_min: 6576806.640625 y_max: 6576835.9375
```

You can run the code yourself [on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/InvolvedPinkLava).

The one coordinate that fails to work with this pattern doesn't seem to follow the rules that you posted in your question.

Comment: The effort (Y). :D

Comment: Interesting approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "&BBOX=151406.25%2C6579062.5%2C151875%2C6579531.25&"
ans = a.split('=')[1].split('&')[0].split('%')
```

Split can be helpful here rather than a complex regex but that also depends upon what kind of strings do you have in full.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this also seems to work; not quite sure if there might be any  run-time differences between this and Jim Wright's answer though.

```
import re

coords = ["&BBOX=151406.25%2C6579062.5%2C151875%2C6579531.25&",
"&BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576689.453125%2C156328.125%2C6576718.75",
"&BBOX=156328.125,6576806.640625%2C156357.421875%2C6576835.9375",
"&BBOX=156328.125,6576748.046875,156357.421875,6576777.34375& ?BBOX=156328%2C125%2C6576777%2C34375%2C156357%2C421875%2C6576806%2C640625&",
"&BBOX=156269.53125%2C6576689.453125%2C156298.828125%2C6576718.75&",
"&BBOX=156298.828125%2C6576718.75%2C156328.125%2C6576748.046875",
"?BBOX=156386.71875%2C6576806.640625%2C156416.015625%2C6576835.9375&"]

r = re.compile(r"&BBOX=(.+?)(?=&|$)")

x_coords = []

def split_coords(coords_string):
    if "%2C" in coords_string:
        bbox = coords_string.split('%2C')
    else:
        bbox = coords_string.split(",")
    x_min, x_max = [bbox[0], bbox[2]]
    return (x_min, x_max)

# If a match is found using the regex, split the coords and add the x_min and x_max coords to the x_coords array
for i in coords:
    match = r.match(i)
    if match:
        match = match.group(1)
        x_coords.append(split_coords(match))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comments where very helpful in getting me thinking in another way. I just hadn't noticed that %2C was a common separator between the coordinates. I modified my regex to:

rexp_bbox = r"(^.+BBOX=(?P\d.*?)(%2C)(?P\d.*?)(%2C)(?P\d.*?)(%2C)(?P\d.*?)(\s|&|\"))"

And it does the trick as i'm using the regex in a log file parsing where i count the number of certain bounding boxes (the coordinates in my question are the corner coordinates of the bounding box)